# Simple VBA Code Giving different results with the same inputs

Tags: excel, vba, variables, iteration, finance

I hope everyone is doing well. Here is my VBA code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Function sdportefolio(w As Range, corr As Range, sd As Range) As Double
    Dim n As Double, i As Double, j As Double, cumul As Double
    
    n = w.Rows.Count
    
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To n
            cumul = cumul + w(i, j) * corr(i, j) * sd(i) * sd(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    sdportefolio = cumul
    
End Function
```

I wanna use this vba function to find the standard deviation of a portfolio using the weights, correlation and sd of each of it's assets.
**The problem is that it's giving me different resultats for the exact same inputs... So the output changes depending on which cell I use as an input...**

I would assume it's a variable problem but I'm really not too sure.

Ty for your help ! :D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icJmL.png)

Comment: Are you sure the inputs are different? Real value Excel is using in each cell is the one you see in the formula bar, not the one you see in the cell formatted.

Comment: Can you update your photo to highlight the inputs you are selecting on the sheet? This will help us know how to relate your formula to the sheet you shared. You can also just use `FORMULATEXT` below so we can see. Also, if the output is wrong, can you also add the expected answer below the udf output?

Comment: thanks for the help everyone... i just realized I was being dumb and I wanted to write w(i) * w(j) and not w(i,j)... sorry about that I'm really tired gonna head to sleep I promise :P